# Pubnub class not working in next.js server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, async-await, pubnub

I'm trying to use pubnub access manager with next.js, but the PubNub class works fine in the client side but when I try to run it next.js server it doesn't work!

*api/pubnub/*

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
try {
    const authKey = generateAuthKey();
    const pubnub = new PubNub({
        publish_key: "pub-c-..",
        subscribe_key: "sub-c-..",
        secret_key: "sec-c-..",
        userId: "myUniqueUserId",
    });

    const token = await pubnub.grant(
        {
            channels: ["chats.room1", "chats.room2"],
            authKeys: [authKey],
            ttl: 1440,
            read: true,
            write: true,
        },
        function (status: any) {
            // console.log(status);
        }
    );
    res.status(200).json(authKey);
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(500).json(error);
}
}
```

The message Error I get: "500 (Internal Server Error)".

pubnub version: "^3.16.5"

Full Axios Error:

```
{
"message": "Request failed with status code 500",
"name": "AxiosError",
"config": {
    "transitional": {
        "silentJSONParsing": true,
        "forcedJSONParsing": true,
        "clarifyTimeoutError": false
    },
    "transformRequest": [
        null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
        null
    ],
    "timeout": 0,
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
    "maxContentLength": -1,
    "maxBodyLength": -1,
    "env": {
        "FormData": null
    },
    "headers": {
        "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "method": "post",
    "url": "/api/pubnub/",
    "data": "{}"
},
"code": "ERR_BAD_RESPONSE",
"status": 500
```

}

This error from my console

```
error - TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'EventEmitter' in undefined
at keepAliveIsEmbedded (/node_modules/pubnub/node.js/lib/xdr.js:12:25)
at Object.createInstance (/node_modules/pubnub/node.js/lib/xdr.js:183:9)
at new CREATE_PUBNUB (/node_modules/pubnub/node.js/pubnub.js:69:25)
at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: What are the details of the error messages? Can you reproduce with PN SDK logs enabled? https://www.pubnub.com/docs/sdks/javascript/troubleshooting

Comment: Wait, are you getting the 500 from PN or due to the fact that you are hard-coding the 500 status code?

Comment: Also, you are using Access Manager v2 (`grant`) which is deprecated. Please use v3 (`grantToken`).

Comment: No It is not because I hard-coded the 500 status code, even if I remove this line I still get "Request failed with status code 500" from Axios, this happen when I'm trying to initialize the Pubnub object `new PubNub({....})`, I'm using pubnub version: "^3.16.5" maybe this is the problem?

Comment: @CraigConover I updated the question with Axios error object, If you need anything else please tell me. thanks.

Comment: Also, I can't upgrade the pubnub version, for comparability with other products in my company that still using this version and I can't ask them to upgrade their version if I upgrade mine.

Comment: I think you are maybe mixing syntax of different versions of the PubNub Node SDK. Which version are you using? If v3.x then in your `new PubNub` code, `userId` should be `uuid`. If v4.x or later, then `publish_key`, `subscribe_key` and `secret_key` should be `publishKey`, `subscribeKey` and `secretKey`. That might be the root cause, but make those changes and report back if you have same/different error or success.

Comment: Sorry, I see you already told me the SDK version :) Just change `userId` to `uuid` and you should be good. Hope that is root cause.

Comment: And just for clarity, all versions of all PubNub SDKs regardless of language can interoperate with each other. Some newer SDKs have more features or more data in the payloads but they are all compatible at a base level of the oldest SDK. I see you submitted that as a separate post, too. Answered there, too.

Comment: SDK compatibility and EOL Policy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75838229/can-two-platforms-with-different-pubnub-versions-talk-to-each-other

Comment: Another possible issue is perhaps that our Node SDK v3 does not support `async/await`. I could be wrong but at that time, the language syntax only supported callback structures.

Comment: I changed `userId` to `uuid` but it doesn't solve the problem. 

So this means the only way to solve this is to upgrade pubnub version? 

Do you have a link to make the migration process easy, because I changed the version to v7 but it seems that there are a lot of things that I have to change.

Comment: something else is wrong with your code but I don't know what it is with the current details. I would advise sending all the details, code, logs, errors possible to support@pubnub.com for further investigation (it's free and it's great service). Include link to this post, too, so we can post back with an answer.