# Can two platforms with different Pubnub versions talk to each other?

Tags: javascript, pubnub

Let's say that I have a mobile application that use pubnub v3 and a web application that use pubnub v7, can these two applications talk to each others (ex: if I send a message from the mobile can the web see it and vice versa)?

Comment: Yes.  You can do it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## PubNub SDK Interoperability

All versions of all PubNub SDKs regardless of language can interoperate with each other. Some newer SDKs have more features or may carry more meta-data in the response (subscribe responses, for example) but they are all compatible at a base level.

It's recommended that you keep your SDKs on a version that is no older than 1 year or at the very least [avoid using any officially EOL'ed SDK version](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/sdks/javascript/end-of-life).